# I am trying to solve constant is not surjective through coq

Tags: coq

This is the work I have so far. And I'm seemed to be stuck here. If anyone has any idea I would appreciate the help.

```
Definition relation (X Y : Type) := X -> Y -> Prop.
Definition surjective {X Y : Type} (R: relation X Y) := 
forall y : Y, exists x : X, R x y.
Definition constant {X:Type} (c:X) := fun x y : X => y = c.
Definition injective {X Y : Type} (R: relation X Y) := forall x1 x2: X, forall y : Y, (R x1 y) -> (R x2 y) -> x1 = x2.

Theorem const_not_sur : forall c:nat, ~surjective (constant c).
Proof.
unfold not.
unfold surjective.
unfold constant.
intros.
destruct (H c) as [x H1].
destruct x.
```

Supposedly this problem can be solved using n_Sn method. If you think such method can be used, where would it be?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a contradiction, you should try to destruct `H (S c)`instead of `H c`, giving a hypothesis `S c = c`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pierre, a contradiction with `S c` indeed works. Note though that you don't have to use the `n_Sn` lemma, since a proof by induction would also work. In SSReflect, this would yield:

```
Theorem const_not_sur : forall c:nat, ~surjective (constant c).
Proof. by move=> c /(_ (S c)) [x /eqP]; elim: c. Qed.
```

Note that `/eqP` allows you to move to the boolean domain, thus enabling a direct use of induction (via `elim`), which is also how the `n_Sn` lemma could be proved. Also, `S c` can be notated `c.+1`, in SSReflect.